# Embed barcodes in web page

Tags: javascript, web-applications, web

What is the best way to serve lot of (say 500) barcode images (code 128 , black&white) in a single html page. I see different options based on my limited experience

1. Generate a static html page with barcodes embedded (base64 encoding) in it.
2. Serve barcodes as image (500 seperate requests!)
3. Use client side JS barcode generator (not sure about the quality and size of available libraries. I saw few, and prefer not to use them)

I use AngularJS for frontend, and the barcodes are generated at the backend. I mostly target modern browser (chrome latest mainly)

Any better way?

Thanks.

Comment: not as if there's much to a 128 barcode, if you've got the appropriate fonts for them.

Comment: Maybe the best way is paging? Who is going to read a page of 500 barcodes?

Comment: 500 barcodes per page, hour, year, minute?

Comment: You can generate barcodes using HTML only if you wish. Barcodes are just a sequence of black and white with specific widths. You can use a simple barcode format like 3of9, or Extended3of9 if you need more characters to generate. A JavaScript example is here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146336/Creating-a-Code-39-Barcode-using-HTML-CSS-and-Java

Code 128 is a little more involved if you want to program it since it requires checksum calculation.

Comment: A more complete HTMLbarcode set based on JavaScript is here: http://www.barcoderesource.com/htmlBarcode.shtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate the barcodes as a 1px tall png sprite.  The file size for a png with 500 barcodes at 100px wide each should be less than 20KB.  Display it in using `background-repeat: repeat-y` and set the `background-position-x` value to `(barcodeIndex * -100) + "px"`:

```css
.barcode
{
    background-image: url(barcodes.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    height: 35px;
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 17px 14px 0;
}
```

250 barcodes from png sprite demo: http://jsfiddle.net/agFvK/4/

Answer (score 1):

In regards to #2, this is just image optimization loading. You are correct that 500 separate requests is not preferable. In regards to this approach, you have a few options.

1) One giant image containing all of your images. Use css positioning to display each of them. This technique is called spriting

2) Do you actually need to display all of the images at once? If you only need them on-demand, only add them dynamically when the user performs an action that should display them.

3) If you do need to display all of them, think of a dynamic loading approach involving scrolling of the page. You might load the first 10 on page load, then as the user scrolls towards the bottom of the screen you load the next 10.

In regards to the javascript libraries to generate them, give that a second thought. That would be the best way to do it, if possible. It sounds like you might be thousands and thousands unique barcodes for lots of users. Pushing this out to the client would mean a lot less load on your server, if this indeed is your situation.

Answer (score 1):

I had many problems using image in large barcodes generated on the server side. The only way I found to solve this problem was generating the barcodes in client side, using HTML and CSS.

You may use PHP to generate the DIVs instead of generating images.

This fiddle illustrates how to do so using js:
http://jsfiddle.net/u7uPJ/2/

This solution uses no js library, only barcode class. Using a library, you can use the following to generate lots of barcodes:

```
$('div.barcodeC').each(function(){
    this.appendChild(Barcode(this.className.match(/barcode\-([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)/)[1], "code128",{barWidth:2, barHeight:50}));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would find algorithm and write my own client-side generator. For this I would consider several options: using left-floated divs for vertical lines (you can utilize border-left, width, border-right, margin-right), using canvas, or using css3 linear gradients.

UPD: I changed my vote to #1 by using base64 encoded images, I think it will be faster for client to display them (because generating barcodes would require some cpu) and you can store the images in database. Could be even better if they were in svg format, so they would be better in print and look sharp on retina screens (btw inline svg is also good).

I don't like mentioned solution to combine images into sprite, I don't think it will be easy to maintain and update such file.